# MvvmCross - MvxTabBarViewController does not show the "More" button when using a Storyboard

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, uitabbar

In my application, I'm using the **MvxTabBarViewController** to display some tabs (the **MvxTabBarViewController** is loaded using a Storyboard):

```
public partial class RootView : MvxTabBarViewController
    {
        private int _tabIndex = 0;

        private Dictionary<int, SectionBase> _sectionBaseForConfig;

        public new RootViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return (RootViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
            set { base.ViewModel = value; }
        }

        public RootView(IntPtr handle)
            : base(handle)
        {
        }

        UIViewController tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4, tab5, tab6, tab7;

        public override async void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            if (ViewModel == null)
                return;

            tab1 = new UIViewController();
            tab1.Title = "1";
            tab1.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
            tab2 = new UIViewController();
            tab2.Title = "2";
            tab2.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;
            tab3 = new UIViewController();
            tab3.Title = "3";
            tab3.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
            tab4 = new UIViewController();
            tab4.Title = "4";
            tab4.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
            tab5 = new UIViewController();
            tab5.Title = "5";
            tab5.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Brown;
            tab6 = new UIViewController();
            tab6.Title = "6";
            tab6.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Brown;
            tab7 = new UIViewController();
            tab7.Title = "7";
            tab7.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Brown;

            var tabs = new UIViewController[] {
                tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4, tab5, tab6, tab7
            };
            ViewControllers = tabs;

            CustomizableViewControllers = null;
            SelectedViewController = ViewControllers[0];
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, even if there are 7 tabs, only 5 are displayed and the "More" button does not show. Anyone got an idea ? I stuck on this problem since 2 hrs now, without any clues :(

Thanks!

Comment: When is used CreateTabFor?

Comment: It's not used on that version, i've edited the code to remove it (but problem is still there :)

Comment: What is the hierarchy? Your RootViewController and everything else

Comment: RootView is the controller that contains all the data (once i'll fix that, i'll replace tab1, tab2, etc. by the correct ViewControllers).

Thanks!

Comment: Exact same code works for me when not using a StoryBoard. IMO it is either related to this or to some other configuration you have.

Comment: Indeed, I'm using a Storyboard too so the problem might come from that but I'm not sure to understand why...

Comment: I never used StoryBoards at all :-/ sorry.

Comment: No problem, i hope someone will have a clue :)

Thanks anyway!